# Incrementing the slug by avoiding Integrity error in django models save method

Tags: django, model, save, slug, integrity

I have a model with two fields as below

**models.py**

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id and not self.slug:
            slug = slugify(self.name)
            try:
                slug_exits = Publisher.objects.get(slug=slug)
                if slug_exits:
                    self.slug = slug + '_1'
            except Publisher.DoesNotExist:
                self.slug = slug
        super(Publisher, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here i am creating a slug based on the `name` field as we can see above

So when we try to create a publisher with `name already exists`, the `save` method of the model will add the `_1` to the end.

And when we again try to create a new record with same `name`, an `Integrity` error will be raised as below

```
>> Publisher.objects.create(name="abc")
   result: slug will be "abc"
>> Publisher.objects.create(name="abc")
   result: slug will be "abc_1"
>> Publisher.objects.create(name="abc")
   result: 

     .................
     .................
     34     del cursor
     35     del connection
---> 36     raise errorclass, errorvalue
     37 
     38 re_numeric_part = re.compile(r"^(\d+)")

IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'abc_1' for key 'slug'")
```

So what i am want is if the title/slug already exists in the database and if slug contains number in it(at the end like abc`_1`), we should increment it that number

So what all i want is to `increment the number in the slug`  as below if the title/slug already exists in the database

```
abc
abc_1
abc_2
abc_3
```

So can anyone please let me know how to implement the above logic of incrementing the slug ?

Thanks in advance......

Comment: Why would you want this? Why not just have the user come up with a unique SEO friendly slug name?

Comment: Actually slug is a unique field, but when a developer or admin tries to create it from python(django) shell, we should do take care of duplication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use loop instead of just a one condition. Try this:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id and not self.slug:
            slug = slugify(self.name)
            slug_exists = True
            counter = 1
            self.slug = slug
            while slug_exists:
                try:
                    slug_exits = Publisher.objects.get(slug=slug)
                    if slug_exits:
                        slug = self.slug + '_' + str(counter)
                        counter += 1
                except Publisher.DoesNotExist:
                    self.slug = slug
                    break
        super(Publisher, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: i think this line slug = self.slug + '_' + str(counter) should be as self.slug = slug + '_' + str(counter)

Comment: Also this is not working in this case,when i tried to create a publisher with same name, its struck, mean the loop is not breaking

Comment: @shivakrishna, no the line should be as written in answer `slug = self.slug + '_' + str(counter)`. You are getting stuck with code that is in answer?

Comment: Actually when i am trying to create a record from the terminal, its taking a long time(not responding) to create a record, i mean the loop is not breaking

Comment: Also it is saving in database like  _1, _2, etc., but we need is abc_1, abc_2 right ?

Comment: @shivakrishna,  Add line `self.slug = slug` just before while loop and try.

Comment: The slug is not at all creating

Comment: the problem is by the above code,the slug is saving as just _1, _2, _3 etc., without slug name in front like abc_1, abc_2 etc.,